# Good practice in condition statments

Tags: c#, syntax, conditional-statements

Currently I'm refactoring my old code, so I have some time to think about how code should look like for somebody else. I managed much of problems, but I always wonder how to prepare good syntax for some nested logical condition. Let's assume that we have following part of code:

```
bool param1;
int  param2;

var result = ( param1 == toCheck.param1) && // to achive condition it always has to be true
    ((param2 == toCheck.param2)) ||
( (!param1) &&
(param2 == defaultValueForParam2));

 // to pass condition param! has to be always true AND ( (params 2 has to be equal) OR (param1 has to be false AND param2 has to be equal with default value)
```

How should it be formated to be more readable for anybody? Are there some rules of formating conditions? Maybe the general solution is just wrong if I need so complicated condition?

My intention was to ask about: how I should use brackets, how I should use indents, grouping, etc?

Comment: you just need to use the `meaningful` variable names and build the conditions normally.

Comment: Yes, in true code the names are meaningful, it is just changed here.

Comment: Then post original meaningful names

Comment: Mr. Sriram, please trust me I use meaningful names, but I cannot share  the commercial code in Internet. And in general, my intention was to ask about: how I should use brackets, how I should use indents, grouping.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a complicated condition, that you cannot make less complicated, it helps to

1. Have good variable names
2. Write a small helper function with a clear name so that the calling code is clear
3. If the conition is used in more that one place Don't Repeat Yourself (see 2.)
4. Reconsider if you can simplify this. Do you really need boolean flags?